# Steps for troubleshooting Sandbox web part "An error occurred while attempting to add the item to the page"

Tags: sandbox-solution

I have a server which is refusing to run **any** Sandbox web parts with the error `"An error occurred while attempting to add the item to the page"`

Steps already performed :-

- These web parts run fine on other servers.
- Normal non-sandbox web parts work fine.
- The SharePoint 2010 User Code Host is running.
- Nothing interesting in ULS lots - just  "WebPartAdder_ItemCannotBeAddedULS"
- A reboot has been performed and
  appropriate incantations murmured.

This sort of error with Sandbox Solutions appears fairly frequently on the newsgroups but with little sign of resolution.

**What steps would you take to troubleshoot an error like this?**

Comment: Ran psconfigui.exe and it start working again... or it could be a fluke... <sigh>